# How to solve NSInvalidArgumentException error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My app is crashing intermittently for users, but unfortunately I am not able reproduce the problem on any of my devices.  The reported error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'

The log trace is not clear about the crash source.
I have attached a log trace.
I'm looking for any pointers that can help me to track this down.

[image: screenshot of sample exception]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: There is a nil value somewhere where you use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: you should add some code here. so that it's easy to find where you got crash.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the crash is in your title...

reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'

It looks like you are trying to create an attributed string from a string but that string is nil.

Add a guard before you do you NSAttributeString initWithString to make sure the string isn't nil i.e.

```
if (string) {
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:string];

    //other code etc...
}
```